# How to map through this data in React?

Tags: reactjs

React/json newbie here.

I have this code `{console.log(this.state.documents)}` which spits out the data below:

[image]

How can I map through this data to display the 3 document titles in list items?

```
this.state.documents.map(document => {
  <li>{document.Title}</li>
})
```

I have tried do this above but it is not working, any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Notice that the internal structure that is printed is { d: { results: [] } }. You need to map through this.state.documents.d.results.

Comment: well, have you tried `this.state.documents.d.results.map((document) => <li>document.Title</li>)`?

Comment: Aprillion thank you!

Comment: Can one of you answer the question properly and I can accept answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

You either need to write return as mentioned by others or you can return lie the following way removing the brackets

```
      this.state.documents.map( document =>  <li>{ document.Title }</li> )
```